# as.POSIXct(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:S results in NAs

Tags: r

I have data that has a FixDateTime column (head below) where it is a character

```
head(df$FixDateTime)
[1] "2017-03-15 15:00:04" "2017-03-16 14:00:48" "2017-03-17 13:00:22"
[4] "2017-03-18 12:00:47" "2017-03-19 11:01:00" "2017-03-20 10:00:47"
class(df$FixDateTime)
[1] "character"
```

Using the code below I try to convert to as.POSIXct and the resulting column is full of NAs. I know that there are no NAs in my dataset

```
df$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(df$FixDateTime, format="%Y-%m%-dT%H:%M:%S", tz="MST")
head(df$DateTime)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I have also run the code in the same way omiting the "T" (with a space instead) and it results in the same thing

I have played with the timezone, and this does not seem to be the issue. I just need a column in the POSIXct format containing date and time.

Comment: Replace `"%Y-%m%-dT%H:%M:%S"` with `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` -- works for me once we replace the typo `%-dT` with `-%d `

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tidyverse` approach

```
lubridate::ymd_hms("2017-03-17 13:00:22",tz = "MST")
```

Comment: It worked- thank you so much, would there be a reason that this would work but the as.POSIXct function would not?

Comment: The base function worked for me, `as.POSIXct("2017-03-17 13:00:22", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="MST")` , I just prefer to work with a tidyverse approach